# jQuery multiselect stays on height 39?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, height, multi-select

I am busy with the multiselect from jQuery UI: http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

But the select box is not growing bigger and stays on the height 39px and won't go bigger?!

Screenshot:
[image]

JS:

```
$("select.multiple").multiselect({});
```

How can i fix this? I get now errors that something is going wrong...

Comment: it will automatically set height from <select></select> size(or may be height from style attribute) attribute .so try giving size atrribute to <select> if it still not works then try this... $("select.multiple").multiselect({}).children('ul').css('height','<height>px');

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem. The problem was because the height I set for the select element is accidentally overwritten by other css style. To make sure the element get the correct necessary height, apply the height to its id, for example:

```
#my-select-element {
    height: 200px;
}
```